# Extension method for type inherit from interface

Tags: c#, interface, extension-methods

I have interface:

```
public interface IBag
{
    public string BagName { get; }
}
```

and class inherit from it :

```
 public class CacheBag : IBag
    {
        private Dictionary<string, object> cache;

        public Dictionary<string, object> Cache
        {
            get
            {
                return this.cache;
            }

            private set
            {
                this.cache = value;
            }
        }

        public string BagName
        {
            get { return "CacheBag"; }
        }
    }
```

I try to create extension method for class inherit from interface :

```
 public static object Retrieve(this IBag bag)
    {
        Type objType = bag.GetType();
        IBag obj = null;
        try
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile appStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            string fileName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}.xml", bag.BagName);
            if (appStore.FileExists(fileName))
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, appStore))
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(isoStream))
                    {
                        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(objType);
                        obj = (IBag)x.Deserialize(sr);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.Message);
        }

        return obj;
    }
}
```

But now it worked that:

```
UserBag users = new UserBag();
                    users.Retrieve();
```

It is possible that I can invoke extension like this :

```
        CacheBag.Retrieve();
```

How should I change my implementation to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to invoke the extension method on an instance of the class:

```
CacheBag bag = new CacheBag();
object result = bag.Retrieve();
```

You need an instance of the class in order to invoke an extension method. As a shortcut you could write:

```
object result = new CacheBag().Retrieve();
```

But if you don't want to create an instance then you don't need to an extension method. You have to define a normal static method.

Comment: But I want to invoke it on type of class. I dont want to create object if I don't need it ;/

Comment: That's not how extension methods work. Please read how extension methods work here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx If you don't need an instance in order to invoke the method then you don't need an extension method - you need a simple static method on the class.